# Auto generate PHP page for Facebook open graph

Tags: php, html, facebook

I'm trying to build an app on Facebook where users can upload their images, share it on their wall and get their friends to 'Like' their photo.

I'm not pretty sure how to do it, I have a page where a user uploads their picture and I would like them to have their own page upon picture uploaded so that their Facebook friends can 'Like' it.

Can I have 1 page with  values or do I need to auto generate for each users?

This is like a Photo Contest.

Comment: You can just upload the photo and track the number of likes on the photo. Another option would be to create a separate page on your site for each photo and then post the URL of that page to Facebook.

Comment: Exactly, but do I build a generic page or do I need to build for each user's photo?

Comment: If you're asking if  you need a separate script for each photo, then no. If you want a unique URL for each, your web server will most likely offer you a method to dynamically rewrite URLs to a single script.

Comment: @MichaelMior ahh yes thanks, I think the dynamic URLs could probably work. Thanks again for your help =)

Answer (score 0):

You could use mysql database to store the data and call it using php when you want to see it, you will only have to create on page, and can automatically update itself when someone uploads a new picture, send to facebook and then store that data into the database so that it can easily be referenced again.